# Acomodando los elemntos dentro de un tr

Tags: html, css, table

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con un th me gustaría que el texto que contiene el th con la clase .nc2 se adaptara hacia abajo pero sin que las flechas de la izquierda y de la derecha se muevan les dejo el codigo html y los estilos que uso.

```js
  $('document').ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    });
```

```css
.well23 {
    min-height: 20px;
    font-family: 'Muli-SemiBold';
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #5a274f;
    border: 1px solid #5a274f;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #fefefe;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.form-horizontal {
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #cecece;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 867px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


table.check td,
table.check th {
    /*border: none;*/
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    /*padding: 0.2rem;*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-break: keep-all;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

table.check th.check {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #5a274f;
    min-height: 20px;
    /*max-width: 80px;*/
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
}


.nc1 {
    min-width: 37px !important;
    max-width: 37px !important;
}

.nc2 {
    min-width: 300px !important;
    max-width: 300px !important;
}
.numcheck {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    min-width: 438px !important;
    max-width: 438px !important;
}

.nc3 {
    min-width: 60px !important;
    max-width: 60px !important;
}

.nc4 {
    min-width: 46px !important;
    max-width: 46px !important;
}

.nc5 {
    min-width: 45px !important;
    max-width: 45px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.nc6 {
    min-width: 45px !important;
    max-width: 45px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.A1 {
    min-width: 30px !important;
    max-width: 30px !important;
}

.A2 {
    min-width: 100px !important;
    max-width: 100px !important;
}

.A3 {
    min-width: 60px !important;
    max-width: 60px !important;
}

.A5 {
    min-width: 55px !important;
    max-width: 55px !important;
}
.A6 {
    min-width: 35px !important;
    max-width: 35px !important;
}
.A7 {
    min-width: 25px !important;
    max-width: 25px !important;
}


.active {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.desactive {
    background-color: grey;
}

.insumo {
    display: none;
}

span:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.meta{
    height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../resources/css/aplicaciones/estilos.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container-fluid">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="formlogro" name="formlogro">

            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered check" id="check">
                        <thead class="table-header check">
                            <tr class="check">
                                <th class="check nc1">
                                    <p style="cursor: pointer;"><i
                                            class="far fa-plus-square" onclick="" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            data-placement="top" data-original-title="Añadir check"></i></p>
                                </th>
                                <th class="check nc2">Check</th>
                                <th class="check nc3">Acciones</th>
                                <th class="check nc4">Avance 0 %</th>
                                <th class="check nc5">F. planeada</th>
                                <th class="check nc6">F. final</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="check">
                            <tr class="active" id="check_re_0" style="height: 70px;">
                                <th class="nc1" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                    <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fas fa-eye"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                            data-original-title="ocultar check" style="color: purple;"></i></span>
                                    <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="far fa-edit"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                            data-original-title="Editar check" style="color: purple;"></i></span>
                                    <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                            data-original-title="Elimina check" style="color: purple;"></i></span>
                                </th>
                                <th class="nc2" style="padding-left: 2px;">
                                    <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                            data-original-title="Insumos de entrada"></i></span>
                                    <span class="numcheck" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                        data-original-title="1.-prueba-BPerea(Difusión)"><b>
                                            1.-prueba</b>-BPerea(Difusión)este texto quiero que se despliege hacia abajo</span>
                                    <span style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                            data-original-title="Insumos de salida"></i></span>
                                </th>
                                <th class="nc3">
                                    <span><a style="display: inline-block;color:red;"><i class="fas fa-file-archive"
                                                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                                data-original-title="Último archivo"></i></a></span>
                                    <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;color:purple"><i data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            data-placement="top" data-original-title="Versiones"
                                            class="fas fa-archive"></i></span>
                                    <span><a style="color: purple;display: inline-block;"><i data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                data-placement="top" data-original-title="Añadir entregable"
                                                class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a></span>

                                    <span><a href="" style="display: inline-block;color:purple"><i data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                data-placement="top" data-original-title="Redactar asunto"
                                                class="far fa-edit"></i></a><a></a></span><a>
                                        <span></span></a><a onclick="" style="display: inline-block;color:purple"><i
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Insumos"
                                            class="fas fa-coins"></i></a>
                                </th>
                                <th class="nc4">
                                    <progress id="file" style="width: 32px;" max="100" value="0"></progress> <span>0
                                        %</span>
                                </th>
                                <th class="nc5">
                                </th>
                                <th class="nc6">
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero y puedan ayudarme de ante mano muchas gracias

este es el resultado de las modificaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero tu `numb check` tiene estilos para que sea un `text truncate` texto truncado, quita eso y el texto se acomodara hacia abajo, para lo de las flechas puedes usar un `position: absolute` y lo centra y lo acomodas con left top right o bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este sería el resultado de lo mencionado en el comentario por si no me di a entender muy bien.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
```

```css
.well23 {
min-height: 20px;
font-family: 'Muli-SemiBold';
font-size: 11px;
padding: 8px;
background-color: #5a274f;
border: 1px solid #5a274f;
border-radius: 0px;
color: #fefefe;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.form-horizontal {
margin-left: 10px;
background-color: #cecece;
padding: 10px;
width: 867px;
border-radius: 10px;
}


table.check td,
table.check th {
/*border: none;*/
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
/*padding: 0.2rem;*/
/*white-space: nowrap;*/
/*word-break: keep-all;*/
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

table.check th.check {
font-size: 10px;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #5a274f;
min-height: 20px;
/*max-width: 80px;*/
border: none;
text-align: left;
}


.nc1 {
min-width: 37px !important;
/*max-width: 37px !important;*/
}

.nc2 {
min-width: 300px !important;
/*max-width: 300px !important;*/
position: relative;
padding: 0 10px 0 25px !important;
}
.numcheck {
/*display: flex;*/
/*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
/*overflow: hidden;*/
/*text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
min-width: 438px !important;
/*max-width: 438px !important;*/
}

.nc3 {
min-width: 60px !important;
/*max-width: 60px !important;*/
}

.nc4 {
min-width: 46px !important;
/*max-width: 46px !important;*/
}

.nc5 {
min-width: 45px !important;
/*max-width: 45px !important;*/
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.nc6 {
min-width: 45px !important;
/*max-width: 45px !important;*/
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.A1 {
min-width: 30px !important;
/*max-width: 30px !important;*/
}

.A2 {
min-width: 100px !important;
/*max-width: 100px !important;*/
}

.A3 {
min-width: 60px !important;
/*max-width: 60px !important;*/
}

.A5 {
min-width: 55px !important;
/*max-width: 55px !important;*/
}
.A6 {
min-width: 35px !important;
/*max-width: 35px !important;*/
}
.A7 {
min-width: 25px !important;
/*max-width: 25px !important;*/
}


.active {
background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.desactive {
background-color: grey;
}

.insumo {
display: none;
}

span:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.meta{
height: 70px;
}


/**/


i[class*="fa-arrow"] {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
}

i.fa-arrow-left {
right: 8px;
}


i.fa-arrow-right {
left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../resources/css/aplicaciones/estilos.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="formlogro" name="formlogro">

        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <section>
                
                <table class="table table-bordered check" id="check">
                    <thead class="table-header check">
                        <tr class="check">
                            <th class="check nc1">
                                <p style="cursor: pointer;"><i
                                        class="far fa-plus-square" onclick="" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                        data-placement="top" data-original-title="Añadir check"></i></p>
                            </th>
                            <th class="check nc2">Check</th>
                            <th class="check nc3">Acciones</th>
                            <th class="check nc4">Avance 0 %</th>
                            <th class="check nc5">F. planeada</th>
                            <th class="check nc6">F. final</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="check">
                        <tr class="active" id="check_re_0" style="height: 70px;">
                            <th class="nc1" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fas fa-eye"
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                        data-original-title="ocultar check" style="color: purple;"></i></span>
                                <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="far fa-edit"
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                        data-original-title="Editar check" style="color: purple;"></i></span>
                                <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                        data-original-title="Elimina check" style="color: purple;"></i></span>
                            </th>
                            <th class="nc2" style="padding-left: 2px;">
                                <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                        data-original-title="Insumos de entrada"></i></span>
                                <span class="numcheck" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                    data-original-title="1.-prueba-BPerea(Difusión)"><b>
                                        1.-prueba</b>-BPerea(Difusión)este texto quiero que se despliege hacia abajoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo0000000000000ooooooooo</span>
                                <span style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                        data-original-title="Insumos de salida"></i></span>
                            </th>
                            <th class="nc3">
                                <span><a style="display: inline-block;color:red;"><i class="fas fa-file-archive"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                            data-original-title="Último archivo"></i></a></span>
                                <span onclick="" style="display: inline-block;color:purple"><i data-toggle="tooltip"
                                        data-placement="top" data-original-title="Versiones"
                                        class="fas fa-archive"></i></span>
                                <span><a style="color: purple;display: inline-block;"><i data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            data-placement="top" data-original-title="Añadir entregable"
                                            class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a></span>

                                <span><a href="" style="display: inline-block;color:purple"><i data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            data-placement="top" data-original-title="Redactar asunto"
                                            class="far fa-edit"></i></a><a></a></span><a>
                                    <span></span></a><a onclick="" style="display: inline-block;color:purple"><i
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Insumos"
                                        class="fas fa-coins"></i></a>
                            </th>
                            <th class="nc4">
                                <progress id="file" style="width: 32px;" max="100" value="0"></progress> <span>0
                                    %</span>
                            </th>
                            <th class="nc5">
                            </th>
                            <th class="nc6">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                
                <secion>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Este sería el resultado si no me equivoco

Comment: hola gabriel muchas gracias ,pero sigue sin ajustarse el texto , te adjunto una captura de pantalla en la pregunta

Comment: Dame un minuto, voy a chequearlo bien y lo corrijo

Comment: @carlosbecerra acabo de verificar y todo se debe a que estas manejando un ancho fijo dentro de cada seccion de la tabla... yo te recomendaría que si quieres manejar un ancho fijo de la tabla, sea un `div` o un `section` que encapsule a la tabla y esta tenga el `width` fijo y en la tabla solo manejes un ancho fijo con las columnas pequeñas, aunque tampoco lo veo bien hacerlo asi.

Comment: ok comprendo y como me recomiendas que quede ?

Comment: Ya esta editada la respuesta con la forma correcta de hacerlo